# XPath Function looking for "CC130"

Tags: xml, xpath

Hi im trying to work out what the function would be to just showcase all the books which are on course "CC130" for example?

i have this "/bookcollection/items/item/courses/course" which shows every course possible?

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <bookcollection>
     <item id="59113">  
     <title>Computer science : a modern introduction /</title>
     <isbn>0131659456</isbn>
     <url>http://library.hud.ac.uk/catlink/bib/59113</url>
     <borrowedcount>29</borrowedcount>
     <courses>
        <course>CC100</course>
        <course>CC130</course>
        <course>CX290</course>
     </courses>
  </item>
  <item id="59118">
     <title>Computer networks : protocols, standards, and interfaces /</title>
     <isbn>0131660918</isbn>
     <url>http://library.hud.ac.uk/catlink/bib/59118</url>
     <borrowedcount>19</borrowedcount>
     <courses>
        <course>CC100</course>
     </courses>
  </item>
  <item id="59131">
     <title>Computer-based instruction : methods and development /</title>
     <isbn>0131685929</isbn>
     <url>http://library.hud.ac.uk/catlink/bib/59131</url>
     <borrowedcount>43</borrowedcount>
     <courses>
        <course>CC100</course>
        <course>CC300</course>
     </courses>
  </item>
  <item id="59176">
     <title>Computer networks : protocols, standards, and interfaces /</title>
     <isbn>0131756052</isbn>
     <url>http://library.hud.ac.uk/catlink/bib/59176</url>
     <borrowedcount>10</borrowedcount>
     <courses>
        <course>CC100</course>
     </courses>
  </item>
  </bookcollection>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
//item[descendant::course/text() = 'CC300']
```

Working example: http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm?state=CF

Comment: quick question what would the function be to show just one item id say i were to search item id 59131?

Comment: @Dan - You could use something like `//item[@id = '59131'][descendant::course/text() = 'CC300']`. You should edit the question - you may get better answers (Ian's answer seems neater, for example)

Answer (score 1):

You need a *predicate*:

```
/bookcollection/item[courses/course = 'CC130']
```

This would match all `item` elements in the `bookcollection` that have at least one `courses` child containing at least one `course` child whose value is `CC130`.  When the XML structure is regular like this it's generally more efficient to spell out all the steps explicitly rather than using `//` or `descendant::` (e.g. `//item[.//course = 'CC130']` would also work but would involve searching the whole tree at all levels for elements named `item` - but you know that the only interesting `item` elements are those directly under the `bookcollection`).